# Do I need to purchase a subscription to claim my mount?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was playing Hearthstone and it told me that I got a free mount called "Hearthsteed" in WoW.

Do I need to be a paid subscriber in order to claim it? Or can I claim it with my starter account?

Comment: I think you're referring to the Hearthsteed, which is a mount (not a pet). Without testing, I think you would be able to do so, but I believe the starter edition is capped at 20 which is when you unlock mounts.

Comment: @twobugs ugh, yes. The mount. Lemme update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to have a paid subscription to claim your Hearthsteed.

However, the Hearthsteed has a level requirement of 20. Since the World of Warcraft Starter Edition only gives you until level 20, you will not be able to use the item, until you upgrade your account.